# Comparing pieces of strings in C# and removing items from collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, c#-4.0

I have a piece of code written in C# like this:

```
foreach (var item in allNegatives)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < _items.Count(); index++)
    {
        if (_items[index].Title.ToLower().IndexOf(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            _items.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Where the `_items` collection is a List of strings (long titles)... Now as you can see I have a foreach loop and a for loop inside to check whether a Title inside the _items collections contains one of the "negative" phrases. Negative phrase simply means if the title contains it, I would like to remove that item from the collection...

The problem here is that this doesn't works the way I want it... ?

If I had 100 items in collection and some of them were like this:

```
Samsung galaxy s8 1200 mAh

Samsung galaxy s8 1200 mAh

Samsung galaxy s7 1200 mAh

Samsung galaxy s7 1200 mAh

Samsung galaxy s6 1200 mAh
```

And if the negative phrases are:

```
S8 and S7
```

The output that I get is:

```
Samsung galaxy s7 1200 mAh

Samsung galaxy s7 1200 mAh

Samsung galaxy s6 1200 mAh
```

For some reason it seems that the 2nd time the foreach loops the items containing that phrase aren't removed from the collection, and I'm not sure why.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: In the example you gave, are you wanting to remove all items where `Title` contains `S7` or `S8`?

Comment: `Title.ToLower().IndexOf(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` It doesnt make sense to use `ToLower` if you use `OrdinalIgnoreCase`. You don't need to create a new lowercase string if you want to ignore the case.

Comment: @StephenMuecke any item in the collection that contains either S8 or S7

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes good point , completely forgot on that! :)

Comment: You could just use a `.Contains()` to get the items to delete, and then a `.RemoveAll()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke with the OrdinalIgnoreCase right ?

Comment: Or use `.ToLower()` or `.ToUpper()` on both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44047617/284240) has explained why it doesnt work that way, you are iterating all indexes and in this loop you are removing items. That can cause incorrrect results or exceptions.

Maybe you want to use [`List.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
_items.RemoveAll(i => allNegatives.Any(n => i.Title.IndexOf(n, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

This also avoids using `Title.ToLower` which is unnecessary if you use `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: Yeah, RemoveAll is probably the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You're skipping items.

Imagine this list:

```
0 s5
1 s8 <-
2 s7
3 s6
```

You're at index 1. S8 matches, so you remove it from the list, which now looks like this:

```
0 s5
1 s7 <-
2 s6
```

You're still at index 1, but it now contains s7. You iterate, and you're now at 2. You've skipped s7 even though it matches.

If you iterate backwards, this won't happen:

```
foreach (var item in allNegatives)
{
  for (int index = _items.Count() - 1; index >= 0; --index)
  {
      if (_items[index].Title.IndexOf(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
      {
        _items.RemoveAt(index);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ for this. Here is example how you can do this:

```
List<string> list= new List<string>()
{
    "Samsung galaxy s8 1200 mAh",
    "Samsung galaxy s8 1200 mAh",                
    "Samsung galaxy s7 1200 mAh",
    "Samsung galaxy s7 1200 mAh",
    "Samsung galaxy s6 1200 mAh"
};
List<string> negativePhrs= new List<string>(){"s7","s8"};
list = list.Where(x=> !negativePhrs.Any(y=> x.ToLower().Contains(y.ToLower()))).ToList();
foreach(var a in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want to remove from items or allNegatives?

Does this do what you want to do?

```
var things = new List<Thing> {new Thing { Title="Bob"}, new Thing {Title="Carol"}, new Thing {Title="Dave"}, new Thing {Title="Alice"} };
var items = new List<string> {"foo", "bar", "Alice", "Dave"};
var result = items.Where(x => !things.Exists(y => y.Title == x)).Select(z=>z);
```

This prints

```
foreach(var r in result)
   Console.WriteLine(r);

foo
bar
```

So it has removed Alice and Dave from items because they are Titles in things. But I think maybe you want to remove from things instead?